# dynamic auto-complete input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Materialize as a front-end framework for my project.

I have used their `auto-complete` input field for this purpose and I am providing the data for that auto complete input field through JSON. It is working fine but now I want to add another autocomplete input-field like that and I am using jquery's append method for that.

I am getting the structure for the input field but unfortunately the `dropdown` isn't showing up. When i inspected the elements in the browser, I saw that the `dropdown` for the dynamically generated input field is not showing up. Below is the code for the input field.

**HTML and CSS**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s4 offset-s4">
        <a class="btn grey darken-3 squared left" id="add">add</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" id="dynamic">
    <div class="col s2 offset-s2">
        <input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete input-item" name="item">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $("#add").click(function(){
        i++;
        $('#dynamic').append('<div class="col s2"><input type="text" id="autocomplete-input" class="autocomplete input-item" name="item"></div>');
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firslty , the element with autocomplete-input id should be used once. As ids cannot be used multiple times. When you append the field, you are creating elements with same IDs. Use class selector THEN you have to call the autocomplete script. For this case use your auto-complete script on class instead of id.

Comment: Try with different ID.

Comment: I don't think that is the problem because if I use the auto-complete input field multiple times with same id it works, provided that i generate them statically.